# Loading Office js addin inside Iframe gives error

Tags: office-js

I am trying to load my office addin within an Iframe. However the addin gives an error. The browser console log shows the message "Warning: Office.js is loaded outside of Office client". Is there a limitation in displaying an Office js application within an IFrame?

I am using Chrome browser

The aspx has a js file which loads the Office environment. From the console log I can see that the office environment is loaded. However at the end I get the warning message "Warning: Office.js is loaded outside of Office client"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, looks like it is a limitation, Office JS makes use of `window.external` to communicate with the Office client.

If you iframe it, `window.external` will not return parent's external, so that could be the reason for the below error.

> Warning: Office.js is loaded outside of Office client

You can try updating the external, but I recommend you not to iframe.

`window.external = window.parent.external;`