# Officejs loaded out side of Excel when putting TaskPane in iframe

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

Defining TaskPane in iframe will cause Officejs not working in Excel. Which leads to 'Excel' is undefined. I want to check if this iframe a know limitation or a bug.

**TaskPane.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML Iframes</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <iframe src = "./randomGenerator.html" width = "555" height = "200">
         Sorry your browser does not support inline frames.
      </iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

**randomGenerator**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="output">hello</p>

</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Office.onReady(info => {
            if (info.host === Office.HostType.Excel) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "I am in Excel";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "out of excel";
            }
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

**Result**

[Office.js is loaded outside of Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkBLw.png)

Comment: May I know the scenario of using iframe in taskpane?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55744841/loading-office-js-addin-inside-iframe-gives-error

I tried this workaround it works, but workaround cannot be applied to production. So I still want to know if it can be sovled in a standard way

Comment: @RaymondLu
Hi, using iframe is decided on our server to cover security concern and general back end resource. Any custom page would be under iframe such like TaskPane

Comment: I will ask around and invite the right folk to answer your question

Comment: @RaymondLu Hi, any updates?

Comment: Let me ping again, will get back to you soon

Comment: @RaymondLu  Hi, checking if you got any anwser :)

Comment: I got your comments, I have sent a mail to the corresponding team.

Comment: Are you trying to use the iFrame on Excel Online or Win32?

Comment: @RaymondLu Our web server uses iframe, and Our Excel AddIn uses our web server, we are trying to make our AddIn available in both Windows Excel, Mac Excel, and Excel Online

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted with the PM who owns this area.

iFrame is only supported on Excel Online. So it won't support Windows and Mac.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#take-advantage-of-a-performance-option-in-office-on-the-web) is the document that you could reference

Comment: What is WAC?  Is it mean I coudln't put AddIn page under iframe? what about the workaround I mentioned above

Comment: Sorry, i used a internal terminology, just update the answer.  iFrame is a property that is only supported on Excel online. here is the document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#take-advantage-of-a-performance-option-in-office-on-the-web

Comment: Thank you! What do you think about the workaround I mentioned above

Comment: I actually havent try your workaround, I think you said it doesnt work?

Comment: Do you mean it work on Mac and Win32?  but in the original post, you mentioned Officejs not working in Excel. i am a bit confused

Comment: With that workaround, the office.js works on my Win10, Desktop Excel